# Why are the subnav items in my CSS horizontal menu cutting off text and not wrapping?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, submenu

I am working on converting a site from mostly Flash to mostly CSS / HTML. It is going
swimmingly except for one thing.

Here is the site:

http://cohen.digitaldemo.net

If you mouse over the PRACTICE AREAS top menu option, you'll see the first item in the
submenu reads:

```
ARBITRATION CV for STEVEN
```

What it *should* read is:

```
ARBITRATION CV for STEVEN COHEN
```

Where the line wraps like this:

```
ARBITRATION CV for STEVEN
COHEN
```

Why isn't it wrapping?

Any help with this would be much appreciated...

Comment: I see "ARBITRATION CV for STEVEN COHEN" (wrapped in two lines) ... what browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 130 :

```
.sub-menu li { display:none ;
width:220px ;
    height: 23px;
```

Remove this height.

Answer (score 0):

in the css:

```
.sub-menu li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FC940F;
    display: none;
    height: 23px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 220px;
}
```

you're restricting both the width and the height, so basically it's wrapping but you can't see the wrapped part. You can remove the height so you see the wraps, or increase the width so it doesn't wrap.